# Replacement for Roboguice Ln

Tags: android

I'm trying to switch to [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/), in order to reduce dependencies and improve performance over RoboGuice. However, with RoboGuice, I was using [Ln](https://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/Logging) as a wrapper for my Android logcat calls (nice because it turns off debug/verbose on release build). 
What are good options for an easy to use alternative for a logging wrapper? Most things I've seen are more focused on logging to other storage mechanisms with Log4j/slf4j/etc, which I'm not really that interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try Timber https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber

Does pretty much the same thing.